# How to use lambdify for fuction with derivative?

Tags: python, sympy

I need to calculate derivative to use it for numerical calculations. I tried to use lambdify but it doesn't work with exp from sympy (for example, my function is more complicated but it doesn't work even with exp). I suppose that maybe the problem is that r, l, beta are not integer, but then I do not understand how to use sympy fuctions at all. 
The error is "module" object is not callable.

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify

from sympy.functions.special.gamma_functions import gamma as SymG
from sympy.polys.orthopolys import  laguerre_poly as SymL
from sympy import factorial as SymFactorial
from sympy.functions.elementary import exponential as SymExp

r, l, beta = sym.symbols('r, l, beta')

def chifD(r, l, beta):
    return ( r * beta * l * SymExp(- beta * r / 2 ))


def chiD(r, l, beta):
    return sym.diff(chifD(r ,l, beta), r)

chiLambdified = sym.lambdify((r, l, beta), chiD(r, l, beta), 'numpy')

print(chiLambdified(r, l, beta))
```

Comment: The SymPy exponential function is just called exp. You are importing the exponential module rather than the exp function defined in the module. Just use `from sympy import exp` or `sym.exp`.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin Please post as an answer, so it can be accepted and the question marked answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are seeing is because you are importing the exponential module rather than the exp function:

```
In [2]: from sympy.functions.elementary import exponential                                                                                     

In [3]: exponential                                                                                                                            
Out[3]: <module 'sympy.functions.elementary.exponential' from '/Users/enojb/current/sympy/sympy/sympy/functions/elementary/exponential.py'>

In [4]: exponential(1)                                                                                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-9c27db0dab4a> in <module>
----> 1 exponential(1)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Instead you should use the exp function:

```
In [5]: from sympy import exp                                                                                                                  

In [6]: exp(2)                                                                                                                                 
Out[6]: 
 2
ℯ
```